# SPD workflow activity Start Tasks Process turns workflow into 'Suspended' state

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365, designer-workflow

Has anyone noticed that "Start Task Process" activity in SharePoint designer does not work anymore, on newly created tenants (o365)? 
When I try to create a simple one step workflow which uses "Start Task Process" activity, when starting workflow it goes to a Suspended state with the following message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Incomplete closure detected while
>   loading subroutines for workflow 4896a2e6-6b52-4274-a738-beee0a22eb14
>   in scope
>   /spo/980a5387-9fcc-42ac-b4dc-98107affe6d4/23297437-9ad9-4673-9cdc-e513e00c8903/54d05011-f3e5-410b-9b0a-90b5cbb706cd.

It stopped working like month ago. Still works fine for older tenants (even where custom code sandbox solutions are deprecated).

Any ideas? Have you encountered the same issue?

Comment: I have also encountered others are having issue with "check out item" activity. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4ce48b0-bb9f-4468-8365-1b1e300c102b/sharepoint-2013-workflow-suspended-incomplete-closure-detected?forum=sharepointcustomization